# Query com parameter causando timeout

Tags: c#, query, ado.net

Possuo uma query que ao ser executada com `ADO.NET` leva menos de um segundo para retornar seus dados. Ao adicionar parameters a esta consulta, o retorno mantem-se o mesmo.

Contudo, ao adicionar um parâmetro do tipo `datetime`, a consulta não é executada, dando erro de timeout.

O `parameter` está sendo definido conforme código abaixo;

```
var dataInicioparameter = command.CreateParameter();
dataInicioparameter.ParameterName = "@dataInicio";
dataInicioparameter.Value = dataInicio;
dataInicioparameter.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
command.Parameters.Add(dataInicioparameter);
```

Consulta

```
SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY chave) AS RowNumber1 FROM TabelaX 
               WHERE DataUltimaAtualizacao >= @dataInicio AND DataUltimaAtualizacao <= @dataFim) AS TabelaY
               WHERE RowNumber1 > (@rows * 1000) AND RowNumber1 <=  ((@rows * 1000) + 1000)
```

Comment: @Marconi edição realizada no post

Comment: Não vejo problema na sua query. Tenta definir o tipo primeiro, antes de colocar o valor. Qual o valor de dataInicio? O banco não gera nenhum erro a não ser timeout?

Comment: Não há problemas com a query. Ela é executada se os parâmetros de data forem inseridos 'hard-coded'. Outros parâmetros também funcionam corretamente, o problema está quando adiciona o parâmetro da data. E a exceção levantada é de timeout, sem nenhuma informação adicional =/

Comment: Você definiu o datafim também? Porque seu código só está mostrando pro inicio.

Comment: Foi definido, retirado do código para não ficar extenso

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar `SqlDbType.DateTime` ao invés de `DbType.DateTime`.

```
var dataInicioparameter = new SqlParameter("@dataInicio", SqlDbType.DateTime) 
{ 
    Value = dataInicio;                              
};

command.Parameters.Add(dataInicioparameter);
```

Aproveita e olha [este link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429412/why-do-i-get-a-timeout-when-using-sqlcommand-with-date-parameters) que explica o que pode estar ocasionando este erro.